# Css : Flexbox child's automatically fits height

Tags: html, css, layout

I want the containers child to be image or width height but the child height grows automatically the same as the sibling before it

Live eg https://madarauchihajandkboy.w3spaces.com/noname.html

Like this happens with it

[image: The image]

I want the layout to be like stock images website

Code
Html

```
<div id="main">
<div id="post" >
<div id="top" >
<i>
<img src="${y.profile}" /></i>
<p>${y.name}</p>
</div>
<div id="mid" >
<h1>${y.head}</h1>
<p>${y.sub}</p>
</div>
<div id="mainpost" >
<img src="${y.meme}"/>
</div>
<div id="btm" >
<p><button><ion-icon name="thumbs-up"></ion-icon></button><a>0</a></p>
<p><button><ion-icon name="pricetag"></ion-icon></button><a>0</a></p>
<p><button><ion-icon name="eye"></ion-icon></button><a>0</a></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Css

```
#main {
height:100vh;

width:100vw;

padding:50px;

overflow-y:scroll;

overflow-x:hidden;

display:flex;

flex-wrap:wrap;

gap:30px;

box-sizing:border-box;

scroll-snap-type:y mandatory;

}

#main #post {

scroll-snap-align:center;

flex:300px;

height:auto;

max-width:340px;

width:100%;

padding:10px;

border-radius:10px;

background:var(--post);

position:relative;

display:flex;flex-direction:column;

}
```

And this is for image or video in the post

```
#main #mainpost {

height:auto;

width:100%;

position:relative;

border-radius:9px;

overflow:hidden;

display:grid;place-items:center;

}

#main #mainpost img , #main2 #mainpost img{

height:auto;width:100%;

object-fit:cover;

}
```

I tried adding max height to post but it's same not working
**I want it Like this**
[image]

Comment: The code you have posted seems unclear

Comment: I edited it the css html

Comment: Your css seems invalid. CSS does not start with a selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex layout elements by default have `align-items: stretch` applied so for horizontal flex layouts, this means the minor (vertical) axis, the child elements are stretched to be the height of the tallest element. To avoid this, apply `align-items: start` to `#main`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  position: relative;
  --mbg: hsla(225, 36%, 23%, 1);
  --btnc: hsla(225, 36%, 53%, 0.7);
  --postbtm: hsla(225, 36%, 16%, 1);
  --postbtn: hsla(225, 36%, 19%, 1);
  --postbtnc: hsla(225, 36%, 56%, 0.71);
  --postheadcolor: hsla(225, 36%, 56%, 0.71);
  --post: hsla(225, 36%, 16%, 1);
  --btn: hsl(225, 36%, 36%);
  background: var(--mbg);
}

#main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: start;
  gap: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

#main #post {
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  flex: 300px;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 340px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: var(--post);
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#main #post:hover {
  background: var(--postheadcolor);
}

#main #post #top {
  height: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: var(--postheadcolor);
}

#main #post #top i,
#main #post #top i img {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#main #post #top i {
  margin: 10px;
}

#main #post #mid {
  height: 50px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 40%;
  color: var(--postheadcolor);
}

#main #mainpost {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 9px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

#main #mainpost img,
#main2 #mainpost img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#main #btm {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
  background: var(--postbtm);
}

#main #btm p {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: var(--btnc);
}

#main #btm p>* {
  margin: 0 2px 0 2px;
}

#main #btm button {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: var(--postbtn);
  color: var(--postbtnc);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="post">
    <div id="top"><i><img src="${y.profile}"></i>
      <p>${y.name}</p>
    </div>
    <div id="mid">
      <h1>${y.head}</h1>
      <p>${y.sub}</p>
    </div>
    <div id="mainpost">
      <img src="https://madarauchihajandkboy.w3spaces.com/1.png"></div>
    <div id="btm">
      <p><button><ion-icon name="thumbs-up"></ion-icon></button><a>100</a></p>
      <p><button><ion-icon name="pricetag"></ion-icon></button><a>2</a></p>
      <p><button><ion-icon name="eye"></ion-icon></button><a>10</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="post">
    <div id="top"><i><img src="${y.profile}"></i>
      <p>${y.name}</p>
    </div>
    <div id="mid">
      <h1>${y.head}</h1>
      <p>${y.sub}</p>
    </div>
    <div id="mainpost">
      <img src="https://madarauchihajandkboy.w3spaces.com/2.jpg"></div>
    <div id="btm">
      <p><button><ion-icon name="thumbs-up"></ion-icon></button><a>234</a></p>
      <p><button><ion-icon name="pricetag"></ion-icon></button><a>23</a></p>
      <p><button><ion-icon name="eye"></ion-icon></button><a>98</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="post">
    <div id="top"><i><img src="${y.profile}"></i>
      <p>${y.name}</p>
    </div>
    <div id="mid">
      <h1>${y.head}</h1>
      <p>${y.sub}</p>
    </div>
    <div id="mainpost">
      <img src="https://madarauchihajandkboy.w3spaces.com/1.png"></div>
    <div id="btm">
      <p><button><ion-icon name="thumbs-up"></ion-icon></button><a>234</a></p>
      <p><button><ion-icon name="pricetag"></ion-icon></button><a>10</a></p>
      <p><button><ion-icon name="eye"></ion-icon></button><a>100</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="post">
    <div id="top"><i><img src="${y.profile}"></i>
      <p>${y.name}</p>
    </div>
    <div id="mid">
      <h1>${y.head}</h1>
      <p>${y.sub}</p>
    </div>
    <div id="mainpost">
      <img src="https://madarauchihajandkboy.w3spaces.com/3.jpg"></div>
    <div id="btm">
      <p><button><ion-icon name="thumbs-up"></ion-icon></button><a>123</a></p>
      <p><button><ion-icon name="pricetag"></ion-icon></button><a>56</a></p>
      <p><button><ion-icon name="eye"></ion-icon></button><a>100</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```